# Unescaping special character sequences in Ruby strings

Tags: ruby, string

I am loading text from a file that contains a sequence like:

```
abc\ndef\tghi
```

I want to 'unescape' all special characters, e.g. to treat the `\n` as a newline and `\t` as a tab etc. instead of automatically ending up with e.g. `\\n` or `\\t` in the string.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text will be loaded exactly as it is in the file.  If the file has the literal text \ and n instead of a newline, that is what will be loaded.  If there is a known set of escapes you want to change, you could simply `gsub` them

```
line='abc\ndef\tghi'
line.gsub!('\n', "\n")
line.gsub!('\t', "\t")
```

Comment: I feared an answer like this :-) It puts the onus on the developer to find and replace each known set of escapes. Would have been nice if there was a method like String#unescape to do the job.

Comment: Matt, please see my comment on Telemachus' answer.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there should be some more elegant way to do this, but you could write general-purpose method to do the swapping:

```
def unescape(string)
  dup = string.dup
  escaped_chars = ['n', 't', 'r', 'f', 'v', '0', 'a']
  escaped_subs = {
    "n" => "\n",
    "t" => "\t",
    "r" => "\r",
    "f" => "\f",
    "v" => "\v",
    "0" => "\0",
    "a" => "\a"
  }

  pos = 0
  while pos < dup.length
    if dup[pos] == '\\' and escaped_chars.include? dup[pos + 1]
      dup[pos..(pos + 1)] = escaped_subs[dup[pos + 1]]
    end
    pos += 1
  end

  return dup
end
```

Comment: It's a tough choice between your and Matt's answer. Which will perform better? I have a feeling that in the long run, yours is a better addition to the String class, but for a quick and dirty, I would go for Matt's answer.

Comment: @mydoghasworms Fair enough. I threw this together quickly in response to your comment that "the onus on the developer to find and replace each known set of escapes". This way, you only have to work that all out once. That said, it's probably overkill for 99% of cases.

Answer (score 1):

how about YAML.unescape  ?

```
require 'syck/encoding'
require 'yaml'

YAML.unescape("\\n")
```