# How to convert a string with special characters escaped to the actual special chars

Tags: ruby, char, special-characters

How to convert a string with special characters escaped to the actual special chars?

For example, if I have this:

```
s = "hello\\nworld"
```

The output of `puts` is naturally this:

```
> puts s
hello\nworld
```

But how do I transform it into this?

```
hello
world
```

In other words, is there any function to unescape backslashed characters?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I unescape c-style escape sequences from ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4265928/3425536)

Comment: Best answer I found so far : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22090177/6419007

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to do some string replacements.

```
s = "hello\\nworld"
puts s.gsub("\\n", "\n")
# >> hello
# >> world
```

The downside of this approach is that you have to explicitly list/process all special chars you need to unescape.

Comment: I guess that table substitutions in double quoted will be helpful - [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83EBc.png)

Comment: The approach is something like that, but I really want to avoid that. That makes an ugly code...

Comment: @rigon: yeah well, you're free to prefer elegant `eval`. But I wouldn't recommend that. Out of curiousity, what exactly do you think is "ugly" about this piece of code?

Comment: Because of this: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/syntax/literals.rdoc#strings
To cover all the possibilities is pretty complex. And I agree with you, the `eval` approach is a way worse.

Ruby doesn't something like this `s.unescape_special_chars`?

Comment: @rigon This really *doesn't* make for ugly code. You should be putting your logic in `escape` and `unescape` methods, or using such already written methods as provide by other libraries

Comment: @meagar Which libraries does that?

Comment: @rigon: as meagar says. Also instead of chaining gsubs (`gsub(...).gsub(...).gsub(...)`), you can put all substitutions in a hash/table and do a clever `reduce` on it.

Comment: @rigon See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683985/unescaping-special-character-sequences-in-ruby-strings

Answer (score 0):

You interpolate `\` by `\\` , 
use one backslash instead of two:

```
s = "hello\nworld"
puts s 
#=> hello
    world
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in the question, but I'm receiving an escaped string with backslashes and I want to unescape it, returning to the original string.

Comment: You can use gsub, s.gsub('\\','\')

Comment: @DmitryCat `s.gsub('\\','\')` doesn't work. `'\'` is not a valid string, `\ ` escapes the `'`.

Answer (score -3):

If your string is from a trusted source, you can use `eval`:

```
s = "hello\\nworld"    
eval("\"#{s}\"") # => "hello\nworld"
```

Note that this allows arbitrary code execution:

```
s = "\"; loop { }; \""
eval("\"#{s}\"") # => infinite loop
```

Also this doesn't work for input like `s = "\""`.

Comment: what will happen if s = "User.delete_all" for example or "while true puts 'kek'"?

Comment: @DmitryCat It returns the string as expected? (Note the quotes.)

Comment: yes, but  s = "\"" returns error

Comment: This is really bad, and the fact that you think wrapping it in quotes is somehow effective just demonstrates how problematic `eval` actually is. You have done absolutely nothing to prevent arbitrary code execution. This does **not** "work against malicious input".

Comment: @tuple_cat `'#{User.destory_all}'`, or `'"; User.destroy_all; "'` or any number of a million others.